# Problem using sqflite database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I recently used sqflite but I got this warning in the editor, what should I do?

The library 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are using a version of the `sqflite` package which does not support Dart null-safety which is part of Dart 2.12. Because of this, your whole program cannot be executed as null-safe because you are importing a package which does not make the same guarantees about null-safety.

You need to update to version 2.0.0 or later of `sqflite` (latest version right now is 2.0.0+3) to get support for the new null-safety features.